# How to send XMPP IQ stanza using Smack Android library to server?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack, multiuserchat

I want to send the following IQ stanza to Ejabberd XMPP Server using Smack Android Library. How can I send?

```
<iq from='hag66@shakespeare.example'
    to='coven@muc.shakespeare.example'
    type='set'
    id='E6E10350-76CF-40C6-B91B-1EA08C332FC7'>   

     <subscribe xmlns='urn:xmpp:mucsub:0'
             nick='mynick'
             password='roompassword'>
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages' />
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:affiliations' />
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:subject' />
    <event node='urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:config' />  
  </subscribe> 
  </iq>
```

I want to **Subscribe to MUC/Sub events** as described in https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/

Comment: Hey! did u implemented that ? if yes then please guide me too..

Comment: Hi @Abdul Momen Khan ..no I didn't..what's your purpose of implementation?

Comment: I need to implement the mucsub....

Comment: ok..what feature you want to build?...like Multi User Chat? @Abdul Momen Khan

Comment: Yes Multi User Chat Sub which is enable in ejjabered ..

Comment: ok..for mobile or desktop application? @Abdul Momen Khan

Comment: thanks for reply .. I have implemented it ...

Comment: did you use persistent MUC Room? ..and how you're maintaining presence of the users?

Comment: yes i have used persistent Muc Room.. and presence for joining the room or something else?

Comment: To get the old messages from a room we need to join the room again and fetch the messages..do you have any other solution to fetch the old messages from a room?...without the need to rejoin...

Answer (score 0):

I have done using following code please check might be helpful you.

```
     try {
                IQ iq=new IQ("mynick","urn:xmpp:mucsub:0") {
                    @Override
                    protected IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder getIQChildElementBuilder(IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder xml) {
                        xml.setEmptyElement();
                        return xml;
                    }
                };
                iq.setType(IQ.Type.get);
                //add your urn:xmpp:muclight:0#affiliations extension element
                iq.addExtension();
                iq.setTo(AppConstants.CHAT_HOSTNAME);
                iq.setFrom(connection.getUser());
                debugLog("ping send stanza:"+iq.toXML());
                connection.sendStanza(iq);
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```